# Is there a way torch.mode can be applied multiple times without using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, knn

let us  say arr1 has size  10 and arr2 is size 5 by 5 .(arr2 contains 5 rows of the target indices to be checked)
is there a way of getting the modes of arr1 using the 5 different indices without a loop

i tried this but it only works if arr2 is one dimensional and it returns the mode of the values of the specific indices in arr2

```
modes =torch.mode(arr1[arr2]).values
```

Comment: I tried your it is working. Anyway can you add one example and expected output?

Comment: @DishinHGoyani sorry how does it work for you, it says "too many indices for tensor of dimension 1" for mine

Comment: @DishinHGoyani lets say arr1 has [2,4,5,5,5,7,6,6,4,5] and arr2 has [[0,1,2,3,4],5,[6,7,8,9]] the output should be [5,6]

Answer (score 0):

I tried it is working

```py
arr1 = torch.tensor([2,4,5,5,5,7,6,6,4,5])
arr2 = torch.tensor([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]])

arr1.shape
torch.Size([10])
arr2.shape
torch.Size([2, 5])

torch.mode(arr1[arr2]).values
tensor([5, 6])
```

Comment: What was the issue?